# TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in the context of VueJS

Tags: vue.js, filter, replace

I am filtering some of the characters from the string. I went across few questions which has a same problem ie error in the console, but could not find any good answers.

Here is my string:

```
response_out1|response_out2|response_out3
```

Here is the method that i have used:

```
<vs-select v-model="change">
    <vs-select-item  :key="index" v-bind="item" v-for="(item,index) in 
        userFriendly(out.changes)" />
</vs-select>  

... 

methods: {
        userFriendly (str){
            return str.replace(/_/g, ' ').split('|').map(value => ({text: value, value }))
}
```

Here is the output that i am getting in the vs-select:

```
response out1
response out2
response out3
```

The error that i am getting in my console:

[image]

Here i want to know why i am getting this error and i wanna know how to rectify it and the output that i am expecting is: `Response Out1`, here how to capitalize first character of each word in the same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using a method directly in the template which causes multiple calls whenever your data changes,
you can use computed property to avoid such a scenario, not sure about how you are accessing `out.changes`

this might help you to solve your error and capitalize your text,

```
capitalize(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
},
sentenceCase (sentence) {
    return sentence.split(' ').map(s => this.capitalize(s)).join(' '));
},
userFriendly (str) {
    if (!str) return;
    return str.replace(/_/g, ' ').split('|').map(value => ({text: this.sentenceCase(value), value }))
},
```